# /etc/hosts keeps getting reset. How am I supposed to edit it?

Tags: hosts

Whenever I edit my /etc/hosts file it's not long before I find it is exactly what it was before I edited it. Is there some master file I should be editing, or a gui interface I'm supposed to be using to edit it?

I'm still on Natty.

Comment: Are you working with VPN?

Comment: do you have dnsmasq in your system?

Comment: No vpn, but it looks like dnsmasq-base is installed. I'll look into that and update on results.

Comment: Seeing this problem on 15.04 as well.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+question/191063) post your problem is caused by one of the three possibilities:

1.It's due to dnsmasq defaulting to sys dns settings.

http://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/#comment-39367

http://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/dnsmasq

2.You need to update .

3.Any changes you make to /etc/hosts or /ets/resolv.conf during the VPN session are wiped out when you disconnect from the VPN